# what is oscex-en.url.trendmicro.com

Tags: security, spyware, trojan

I installed fiddler web proxy to debug my webapp and found that something in my computer is constantly connecting to that host.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an address used by TrendMicro's [OfficeScan](http://us.trendmicro.com/us/products/enterprise/officescan-client-server-edition/) security suite.  OSCE keeps pattern files "in the cloud", apparently, which is why it would be accessing the URL all the time (more than you might see for normal antivirus software updating).

Answer (score 0):

Trendmicro is a security software company. This is most likely your anti virus or some other similar software checking for updates or checking against a database.